# Calling power bi rest api using adf integration to generate pdf and put on blob storage

Tags: azure-data-factory, pdf-generation, powerbi-api

Power-bi Integration with ADF to generate pdf and upload it on blob storage
I am trying to call power bi rest API using below method.

For First WebActivity
URL: [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupid}/reports/{reportid}/ExportTo](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7Bgroupid%7D/reports/%7Breportid%7D/ExportTo)
Method: Post
Body: {"format":"PDF"}
Authentication: Service Principal ID
Resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
Source-output:
[Firstoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EVuF.png)

For Second Webactivity
URL:
[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{groupid}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/%7Bgroupid%7D) /reports/{reported}/exports/{exported}/file

In the above URL I am using export ID from the source output of first webactivity
Method: Get
Authentication: Service Principal
Resource: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api
Source-output:
I am getting output in binary format
[Secondoutput Binary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU5ID.jpg)

ThirdActivity:
What would be the third activity? Would It be copy-data activity?
Rest or Http connector? --à Blobstorage

My question what should be the configuration of REST linked-service for converting this format into pdf and putting it on blobstorage?

[REST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRJwf.png)

BASE URL:
Authentication Type:
AAD resource:

I tried using Rest but unable to create Rest.